# Dynamic Sql qyery using prepare statement

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, prepared-statement

Hii i want to create a dynamic query for filtering products. I want filter product from **PRODUCTS** table
 on the basis of certain parameters like

1. Brand
2. Flavour
3. Price
4. Size
5. Type
   i am creating a function in which i am executing MySQL query i want to check which parameter user has used which parameter is used those value will not be null and rest of the not selected parameters will be null. so i am checking the function which is null which is not and passing them in query
   I have tried the following code 
   but it shows null pointer execption with following message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

and u tried printing the query:

> SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 AND brand in (?,? AND Price < ? AND Size < ? AND Type = ?

Follwing is the code:

```
public List<Products> Filter_Itemsl(String[] Brand, String[] Flavour, float Price, float Size, String Type) {

    List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ResultSet rs;
    List<Products> data = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt;

    try {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1");
        if (Brand != null) {
            query.append(" AND brand in (");
            for (int i = 0; i < Brand.length; i++) {
                query.append('?');
                if (i < Brand.length - 1) {
                    query.append(',');
                }
                parameters.add(Brand[i]);
            }
        }
        if (Flavour != null) {
            query.append(" AND Flavour in (");
            for (int i = 0; i < Brand.length; i++) {
                query.append('?');
                if (i < Flavour.length - 1) {
                    query.append(',');
                }
                parameters.add(Flavour[i]);
            }
        }
        if (Price != 0) {
            query.append(" AND Price < ?");
            parameters.add(Price);
        }
        if (Size != 0) {
            query.append(" AND Size < ?");
            parameters.add(Size);
        }
        if (Type != null) {
            query.append(" AND Type = ?");
            parameters.add(Type);
        }
        String Query = query.toString();
        System.out.println(Query);

        stmt = DataBaseConnection.DBConn.getConnection().prepareStatement(Query);

        int i = 1;
        for (Object parameter : parameters) {
            stmt.setObject(i++, parameter);
        }

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs != null) {
            data = new ArrayList<Products>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Products p = new Products();
                p.setTitle(rs.getString("Ttile"));
                p.setCategory(rs.getString("Category"));
                p.setSubCategory(rs.getString("SubCategory"));
                p.setSubCategoryTwo(rs.getString("SubCategorytwo"));
                p.setPrice(rs.getInt("Price"));
                p.setFlavour(rs.getString("Flavour"));
                p.setSize(rs.getFloat("Size"));
                p.setImage(rs.getString("image"));
                p.setBrand(rs.getString("Brand"));
                p.setInstock(rs.getString("instock"));
                p.setInstockQty(rs.getInt("instockqty"));
                p.setType(rs.getString("Type"));
                data.add(p);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(e.getSuppressed());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
    return data;

}
```

Comment: When using the `IN` keyword, you start the clause using the open `(` braces but I don't see a closing `)` braces to complete that clause. Fix that and your query should work just fine.

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'ultimate nutrition',)'Dymatize Elite whey') AND Price < 4000.0 AND Size < 4.0 ' at line 1
This error ocuuer if i close the bracket

Comment: for condition to be true

Comment: Also, ensure `parameters` is a linkedlist instead of arrayList to maintain the parameters order

Comment: You seem to add `)` after every parameter so it ends up like this: `IN (param1,)param2,)` but it only needs to be added at the end like this: `IN (param1, param2)`. Just add the `)` after your for loop.

Comment: Problem resolved but when i pass value of all parameters then it works but if i skip any parameter then it doesn't work 
why ???

Comment: Check for empty strings. For example `if(!("").equals(Flavor) && Flavor != null) ` apart from null check

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
I tried but it gives this exception now

Comment: @user3660263 `ArrayList` also maintains the order of the data. Maybe you're confusing it with `HashSet`.

Comment: @user748316 `Flavor` is an array, checking `"".equals(Flavor)` is completely unrelated since you're comparing a String with an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing ) for every IN sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the bracket after the for loop

```
if (Flavour != null) {
        query.append(" AND Flavour in (");
        for (int i = 0; i < Brand.length; i++) {
            query.append('?');
            if (i < Flavour.length - 1) {
                query.append(',');
            }
            parameters.add(Flavour[i]);
        }
       query.append(")");
    }
```

Comment: can you help me out my query is working when i select all parameters or few